# Why does this Python if condition always return false?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Can anyone tell me why this always returns 'no mortgage'?

```
job = input('do you have a job?, Y or N ')
wage = int(input('how much do you earn a year? '))
if job == 'Y' and wage<20000 :
    print ('you can have a mortgage')
else:
    print('no mortgage')
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong, it works. Job should be "Y" and wage should be less than 20000.

Comment: I think you were tying wage greater than 20000. In that case `if job == 'Y' and wage>20000:` will work

Comment: You have to tell us what _exactly_ you're inputting, or we can't help you...

Answer (score -1):

If the users input is lowercase it will return 'no mortage'. To make sure the user's input is always uppercase use

```
if job.upper() == 'Y'
```

Comment: This might not be the problem; we don't know if he was inputting "y" or "Y" in the first place.